# Can't run HTTP request when call it from click event on JForm button while it works fine when call it from main Class

Tags: java, swing, httprequest

I have method to call web service of signin and it is working fine when call it from main() method ... but when call it from event handler of button on JFrame I got : Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost/postrec/index.php/api/Site/Login Error.
this is happen at the line code :Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

the Method is :

```
public boolean doLogin(String username, String password) throws MalformedURLException{
        try{
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/postrec/index.php/api/Site/Login");
        Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String responseStr = "";
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; responseStr  = responseStr + (char)c);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);

        return (jsonObject.getString("code").equals("200"));
         }catch(JSONException | MalformedURLException | UnsupportedEncodingException e){
             throw new MalformedURLException(e.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Also post the variation that "is working fine."